# como funciona o auto increment no mysql?

Tags: mysqli, id

Eu quero saber como adicionar uma coluna para que ela seja chave primária e auto-incremento, mas que o valor seja mais alto, exemplo:

> ID :3509. e não apenas 1,2,3,4...etc.

Comment: O "mais auto" que você se refere seria a**L**to (com L)?

Comment: Você pode definir o valor inicial do autoincrement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se você ainda não tem o campo você pode usar o comando `ADD COLUMN`

```
ALTER TABLE `Sua_tabela`
  ADD COLUMN `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Se caso o campo ja exista, você pode utilizar `CHANGE COLUMN`

```
ALTER TABLE `Sua_tabela`
  CHANGE COLUMN `nome_atual_do_campo` `novo_nome_do_campo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`novo_nome_do_campo`);
```

Se caso não quiser alterar o nome do campo é só repetir o mesmo nome:

```
CHANGE COLUMN `nome_do_campo` `nome_do_campo` int(11...
```

E para setar o valor do **AUTO_INCREMENT** use:

```
 ALTER TABLE `Sua_tabela`
    AUTO_INCREMENT=3509;
```

Answer (score 4):

Você tem que setar o valor [inicial do AUTO_INCREMENT para sua tabela.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)

```
ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT=3509;
```

Se você ainda não adicionou uma coluna de identificação, adicione-a

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ADD INDEX (id);
```

Veja um exemplo mais detalhado.

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
ALTER TABLE animals AUTO_INCREMENT = 3509;

INSERT INTO animals (name) VALUES
    ('dog'),('cat'),('penguin'),
    ('lax'),('whale'),('ostrich');

SELECT * FROM animals;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6ebce/1)